# MYSQL UPDATE injection without pipe

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a query like this:

```
update T_table set detail = 'XXXX' where num = 155;
```

which on my php file looks like this:

```
$sql = "update T_table set ".$_GET['field']." = '".$_GET['value']."' where num = ".$_GET['num'];
$output = mysql_query($sql);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to inject SQL where the `XXXX` are in the query. Because they will be replaced by a sting from `$_GET`, and if it is possible how would you do?

**Important**: My MYSQL database is not allowing double pipes (`||`) as a concatenation operator.

Comment: Sql injection by passing value like `B'and%20extractvalue(1,concat(0x0a,(select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema=database() and table_name='users' limit 1,1)));--%20` can be performed to fetch and alter details in the tables

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo)'s [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
$query = $db->prepare("update T_table set detail = :detail where num = :num;");
$query->bindParam(":detail", $_GET['detail']);
$query->bindParam(":num", $_GET['num']);
$query->execute();
```

if you need multiple fields this gets a little more complicated as the user's input can't really be trusted with arbitrary fields:

```
$allowedFields = ["detail", "cost", "name"];
$field = $_GET['field'];
if(in_array($field, $allowedFields) {
    $query = $db->prepare("update T_table set $field = :value where num = :num;");
    $query->bindParam(":value", $_GET['value']);
    $query->bindParam(":num", $_GET['num']);
    $query->execute();
}
```